# What is the best TH9 strategy to get dark elixir?

Tags: clash-of-clans

The strategy I'm using is Pekwarch which is clearly not working for me.

Pekwarch:

- 3 pekkas
- 12 wizards
- 5 wallbreaks
- 66 archers

Works well for trophies, but Pekkas tend to go around the base.

How would I get the dark elixir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pekkas are pretty decent at punching into a base and taking out DE storages and DE drills.  The trick is getting them to path correctly.  As you note, they have a tendency to walk around the outside of the base rather than attacking the inner areas.

The trick is to control their pathing with your cheaper units.  I will lay down archers ahead of the Pekkas to hit the external buildings - this causes the Pekkas to path towards the center of the base rather than just wandering around the outside.

Depending on the layout of the base and the level of the defenses, you may or may not be able to punch all the way to the center, and it's unlikely that you'll 100% with it.  I will try to focus on one side or quadrant of the base that is the closest to my DE targets.

Spells can be used to trash key defenses, like Teslas that are deep in the base where archers/wizards aren't going to get to fast enough, or to take out clusters of defenses like mortars + wizard towers that are too close together.

One other side note: [DE drills are generally worth more than DE storages.](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/6-tips-to-avoid-raiders-in-clash-of-clans/) (see tip #3)

> At TH10, if someone destroys your DE storage, they only get 4% of the contents. In fact, (as of this writing) in a maxed out TH10 base, with collectors and storages full, the Dark Elixir storage will give 3,000 DE if fully destroyed. Meanwhile, the three full drills you get at TH10 can give 1,350 DE each – 75% of whatever is inside them – for a total of 4,050 DE.

I will tend to prioritize attacking bases that have full DE drills rather than full DE storages for this reason.

Comment: Would jump spells help to encourage pekkas to head towards the center?

Comment: @Ellesedil, I think they path towards the closest thing, which is often another building around the outside of the base rather than something inside.  If walls matter, they don't matter very much - I've seen pekkas destroy one building inside a wall area and then break a wall to get inside another wall area before finishing the area they're in.  I haven't played much with jump spells - I mostly take lightning.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different strategies to farm dark elixir at Townhall 9. I personally find it quite easy with Giwiwi. I regularly pull 2-3k dark elixir per raid. Mostly though it comes down to personal preference, troop level, and execution, though base level and trophy league do play a part.

If you are a Townhall 9 and not completely rushed, you should be able to climb to at least crystal, and you will have preferably have at least a level 10 king and level 5 queen. Now there are several ways of going about farming dark elixir. You can take some giants and wizards and try to clear out all the defenses around the dark elixir storage, then send in your heroes to pick off the storage, or you can do a full assault on the base and funnel everything toward the dark storage.

To farm dark elixir effectively, you will most likely need to use quite a bit of elixir for each attack (it doesn't really make sense to use dark troops to farm dark elixir), and it is recommended to take spells, as most people keep their dark storage near the middle of their base and well protected. At th9 you have access to a jump spell, which you can use to help path your troops in going through walls. Earthquake spells can do the same, but again if you want to farm dark elixir you should keep your dark elixir spent per raid to a minimum. The only dark elixir I recommend spending is on 2-3 hogs and a poison spell.

When attacking, it is important that you check for clan troops and kill them before sending in your main force, as they can completely destroy your giants/pekkas/etc before they can get in. I recommend using a few hogs to check, then killing them with a poison or luring them out with a few archers to kill in a corner away from the defenses. Before sending in your main force, it is also important to make a "funnel" for your troops. Basically use wizards/minions/archers to clear buildings on the sides of where you want to attack, so you troops will not be distracted by them, and more likely to path inward.

Note: if you are in a higher league, and can sustain being there, the dark elixir from loot bonus after attacking does help quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

best  is goblins knife- **troop combination is 15 giants 9-10 wiz  few wall breakers few archers and rest goblins. heal spell and one jump spell. Drop the giant and wizards in the defense path leading to dark storage. As the defense line is cleared send in goblins and use the jump spell. cheap and efficient too. Only problem is if dark storage is surrounded by wiz tower.